# Оформление фразы с прямой речью

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли точка в конце этого предложения? Если бы вопрос был оформлен без двоеточия и в кавычках, то точка была бы нужна, а в этом случае, кажется, нет.

Возникает вопрос: «*Относится фланец к элементу оборудования или нет?*»

Comment: Вариант: _**Возникает вопрос: относится фланец к элементу оборудования или нет?**_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возникает вопрос: «Относится фланец к элементу оборудования или нет?»

Точка при оформлении в виде прямой речи не нужна, если есть вопросительный знак.

Comment: Спасибо большое :)